# Three ingredient peanut butter cookies - how to improve texture

Tags: baking, gluten-free

I am Gluten free and I thought these looked good for peanut butter cookies:

1. peanut butter,
2. maple syrup
3. salt.

They really do bake up beautifully. However, they crumble on the way to your mouth.

- I added egg.
  Now the batter has become gummy and pasty.
- I added baking soda.
  While stirring in the baking soda the peanut oil separated from the peanut butter based cookie dough. I baked them and they are an interesting texture of tough and chewy.

What can be done to the original three ingredient cookie recipe that will make them not crumble so much, and not alter the entire texture to a totally different cookie. I think I have run out of options.

Comment: There are 'no bake' peanut butter cookies that use oats as a binder -- but they have a lot more ingredients (you start w/ sugar, butter or margarine + some liquid on the stovetop, then add the oats to hydrate, then mix in the peanut butter & drop by the spoonful onto waxed paper or similar.

Answer (score 3):

I use a recipe that is similar and have good results. I believe that I use 1 cup of peanut butter, 1 cup of sugar, and 1 egg.

These turn out a very nice texture. If I were you I would sub some or all of the syrup for regular sugar to make it a bit dryer and make sure to add an egg.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a little coconut flour, but very little -- it absorbs an enormous amount of moisture.

You could also try adding a blend of coconut flour and oat flour (make your own by grinding rolled oats in your blender or food processor, and sifting the flour to remove the bigger bits, which can be added to soup, stew, spaghetti sauce, smoothies, etc.).